# Parâmetro de método com classe abstrata

Tags: java, parâmetros, método, abstração

Olá. Acredito que minha dúvida seja muito simples, mas realmente não encontrei nenhuma solução, após muita pesquisa.

No Java, Tenho duas classes concretas que estendem uma classe abstrata, conforme o exemplo:

```
public class Animal {}
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() {}
    public void eat() {}
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void eat() {}
}
```

Somente a classe Dog possui o método bark().

Gostaria que um parâmetro de um método aceitasse qualquer objeto Animal, então fiz isso:

```
public void doSomething(Animal animal) {}
```

Mas eu preciso que esse método faça o animal latir, caso seja um cachorro, então tentei isso, sem sucesso:

```
public void doSomething(Animal animal) {
    animal.bark();
}
```

Há alguma forma de fazer o que eu quero?

Obrigado!

Comment: Creio que criar um método equal() para seu animal, e se Animal.equal(Dog) == verdadeiro, latir irá funcionar.

Comment: http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-3932-Comparar-variaveis--ou-equals.html

Answer (score 1):

Pensando apenas em Orientaçao a Objetos, isso não é possível.

O método doSomething recebe a classe Animal, logo, esse método tem que saber o que fazer com esse tipo de classe, o método bark(), pertence apenas ao Dog e não ao Cat, logo, se seu metodo que recebe Animal, receber a classe Cat, porém tentar chamar o método bark(), ele ficaria "perdido", sendo assim, não é possível fazer o que você quer de forma correta.

O que você poderia ter, é um método "Acao" por exemplo, onde na classe Dog vc implementaria o código que faz latir e na classe Cat você implementaria o código que faz miar por exemplo.

Ai seu metodo chamaria animal.Acao() e cada implementação de Animal faz o que tem que fazer...

Se seu método já sabe que vai chamar o "bark()", então, em teoria, vc já sabe que vai receber um cachorro e não um Animal e ai não faz sentido o método receber um Animal como parametro.

Você consegue fazer isso que você quer conforme foi dito nos comentários, utilizando equals e convertendo o objeto, porém, você quebraria o Open/Closed principle, pois a cada nova implementação de Animal, vc teria que adicionar um "if" novo no seu método doSomething para tratar somente esta implementação nova.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, muitíssimo obrigado pelas contribuições, que foram muito úteis. Ainda sou novato no Java e estou patinando em alguns conceitos.

Acabei pensando mais um pouquinho no conceito que estava tentando empregar e vi que não fazia muito sentido (no sentido de orientação a objetos).

Resolvi da seguinte forma:
Criei uma interface "barkable", implementei-a no Dog e defini a restrição no método doSomething() para a interface, ao invés da classe abstrata.

Em código, seria isso:

```
interface Barkable() {
    public void bark();
}
public class Dog extends Animal implements Barkable {
    //...
}
public void doSomething(Barkable animal) {
    animal.bark();
}
```

[]'s!

Answer (score 0):

O Java por si só não faz compara atributos ou objetos, mas existe um método na classe Object que pode ser reescrito para criarmos esse critério de comparação. Esse método é o `equals()`.

O `equals()` recebe um Object como argumento e deve verificar se ele mesmo é igual ao Object recebido para retornar um `boolean`. Se você não reescrever esse método, o comportamento herdado é fazer um == com o objeto recebido como argumento.

Um exemplo clássico do uso do `equals()` é para datas. Se você criar duas datas, isto é, dois objetos diferentes, contendo 31/10/1979, ao comparar com o == receberá false, pois são referências para objetos diferentes. Seria correto, então, reescrever este método, fazendo as comparações dos atributos, e o usuário passaria a invocar `equals()` em vez de comparar com ==.

Você poderia criar um método com outro nome em vez de reescrever equals que recebe Object, mas ele é importante pois muitas bibliotecas o chamam através do polimorfismo.

Exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa extends Object implements Serializable {  
   private int idade;  
   private String nome;  

   public Pessoa() {  
      setIdade(0);  
      setNome("Alguem");  
   }  

   public boolean equals(Pessoa p) {  
      boolean compare = false;  

      if ((this.nome.equals(p.getNome())) && (this.idade == p.getIdade())   )  
         compare = true;  

      return compare;  
   }  
}
```

Até agora é a única maneira que me vem a cabeça.

[Fonte 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

[Fonte 2](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/o-pacote-java-lang/#14-6-integer-e-classes-wrappers-box)

[Fonte 3](http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/3932/Comparar-variaveis-==-ou-equals.html)